# "mobile" link is broken on private beta sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, mobile-web

Repro

1. with a logged off browser go to https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl=https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/
2. click on mobile

   [image: mobile]
3. get redirected to a "broken link" page with the following address:

   ```
    https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Chtml%3E%3Chead%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3ELog%20In%20-%20Politics%20Beta%20-%20Stack%20Exchange%3C/title%3E%20%20%20%20%3Clink%20rel=%22shortcut%20icon%22%20href=%22http://cdn.sstatic.net/politics/img/favicon.ico%22%3E%20%20%20%20%3Clink%20rel=%22apple-touch-icon%22%20href=%22http://cdn.sstatic.net/politics/img/apple-touch-icon.png%22%3E%20%20%20%20%3Clink%20rel=%22search%22%20type=%22application/opensearchdescription+xml%22%20title=%22Politics%20-%20Stack%20Exchange%22%20href=%22/opensearch.xml%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cscript%20type=%22text/javascript%22%20src=%22http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E%20%20%20%20%3Cscript%20type=%22text/javascript%22%20src=%22http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js?v=09cc52bea55d%22%3E%3C/script%3E%20%20%20%20%3Clink%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20type=%22text/css%22%20href=%22http://cdn.sstatic.net/politics/all.css?v=938ecdf8a22c%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cmeta%20http-equiv=%22X-XRDS-Location%22%20content=%22https://politics.stackexchange.com/yadis%22%3E%20%20%20%20%3Cscript%20src=%22http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/third-party/openid-jquery.js?v=eb7d1a32f868%22%20type=%22text/javascript%22%3E%3C/script%3E%20%20%20%20%3Cscript%20type=%22text/javascript%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20document.write('%3Cstyle%20type=%22text/css%22%3E.login-page%20.script-only%20{%20display:%20block;%20}%3C\/style%3E');%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20$(function()%20{%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20openid.init('openid_identifier',%20'',%20'http://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/openid/openid-logos.png?v=8',%20true);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20});%20%20%20%20%3C/script%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cscript%20type=%22text/javascript%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20StackExchange.ready(function%20()%20{%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20StackExchange.realtime.init('ws://sockets-se.or.stackexchange.com');%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20StackExchange.realtime.subscribeToInboxNotifications();%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20StackExchange.realtime.subscribeToReputationNotifications('475');%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20});%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/script%3E%20%20%20%20%3Cscript%20type=%22text/javascript%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20StackExchange.init({%22stackAuthUrl%22:%22https://stackauth.com%22,%22serverTime%22:1355066676,%22enableUserHovercards%22:true,%22site%22:{%22name%22:%22Politics%22,%22description%22:%22Q&A%20for%20people%20interested%20in%20governments,%20policies,%20and%20political%20processes%22,%22isNoticesTabEnabled%22:true,%22recaptchaPublicKey%22:%226LdsB7sSAAAAAAzjgEF_Hd8vXv-C42sa_KyofaGR%22},%22user%22:{%22fkey%22:%22fcd5d158081a53ac7f3aebfbf6556774%22,%22isAnonymous%22:true}});%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20StackExchange.using.setCacheBreakers({%22js/prettify-full.js%22:%22c862bf93b3ec%22,%22js/moderator.js%22:%2237bba549a03e%22,%22js/full-anon.js%22:%22dea47c239bf6%22,%22js/full.js%22:%2255cc88b7d019%22,%22js/wmd.js%22:%2289ec12ce09df%22,%22js/third-party/jquery.autocomplete.min.js%22:%22e5f01e97f7c3%22,%22js/mobile.js%22:%226eb68240242f%22,%22js/help.js%22:%22fc9fb0517db2%22,%22js/tageditor.js%22:%22450c9e8426fc%22,%22js/tageditornew.js%22:%229ac6c13a3a7f%22,%22js/inline-tag-editing.js%22:%2230f72b99548b%22,%22js/revisions.js%22:%228c6bcd93b7fe%22,%22js/review.js%22:%2294bb46ac228f%22});%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/script%3E%20%20%20%20%3Cscript%20type=%22text/javascript%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20StackExchange.using(%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22gps%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20function%20()%20{%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20StackExchange.gps.init(false);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20}%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20);%20%20%20%20%3C/script%3E%3C/head%3E%3Cbody%20class=%22login-page%22%3E%20%20%20%20%3Cnoscript%3E%3Cdiv%20id=%22noscript-padding%22%3E%3C/div%3E%3C/noscript%3E%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20id=%22notify-container%22%3E%3C/div%3E%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20id=%22overlay-header%22%3E%3C/div%3E%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20id=%22custom-header%22%3E%3C/div%3E%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class=%22container%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20id=%22header%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20id=%22portalLink%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20class=%22genu%22%20href=%22http://stackexchange.com%22%20onclick=%22StackExchange.ready(function(){genuwine.click();});return%20false;%22%3EStack%20Exchange%3C/a%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/div%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20id=%22topbar%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20id=%22hlinks%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%20id=%22hlinks-user%22%3E%3C/span%3E%3Cspan%20id=%22hlinks-nav%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20href=%22/users/login%22%3Elog%20in%3C/a%3E%20%3Cspan%20class=%22lsep%22%3E|%3C/span%3E%3C/span%3E%3Cspan%20id=%22hlinks-custom%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20href=%22http://chat.stackexchange.com%22%3Echat%3C/a%3E%20%3Cspan%20class=%22lsep%22%3E|%3C/span%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20href=%22http://meta.politics.stackexchange.com%22%3Emeta%3C/a%3E%20%3Cspan%20class=%22lsep%22%3E|%3C/span%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20href=%22/about%22%3Eabout%3C/a%3E%20%3Cspan%20class=%22lsep%22%3E|%3C/span%3E%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20href=%22/faq%22%3Efaq%3C/a%3E%3C/span%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/div%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20id=%22hsearch%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cform%20id=%22search%22%20action=%22/search%22%20method=%22get%22%20autocomplete=%22off%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cinput%20autocomplete=%22off%22%20name=%22q%22%20class=%22textbox%22%20placeholder=%22search%22%20tabindex=%221%22%20type=%22text%22%20maxlength=%22140%22%20size=%2228%22%20value=%22%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/div%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/form%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/div%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/div%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%20class=%22cbt%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20id=%22hlogo%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20href=%22/%22%20%3EPolitics%20%3Cspan%20class=%22beta-title%22%3Ebeta%3C/span%3E%3C/a%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/div%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20id=%22hmenus%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class=%22nav%20mainnavs%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cul%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20id=%22nav-questions%22%20href=%22/questions%22%3EQuestions%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20id=%22nav-tags%22%20href=%22/tags%22%3ETags%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%20class=%22youarehere%22%3E%3Ca%20id=%22nav-users%22%20href=%22/users%22%3EUsers%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20id=%22nav-badges%22%20href=%22/badges%22%3EBadges%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20id=%22nav-unanswered%22%20href=%22/unanswered%22%3EUnanswered%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/ul%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/div%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class=%22nav%20askquestion%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cul%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20id=%22nav-askquestion%22%20%20href=%22/questions/ask%22%3EAsk%20Question%3C/a%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/ul%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/div%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/div%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/div%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20id=%22system-message-temp%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cscript%20type=%22text/javascript%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20curSystemMessage%20=%20'got%20a%20question%20about%20the%20site%20itself?%20%3Ca%20href=%22http:\/\/meta.politics.stackexchange.com%22%3Emeta.politics%3C\/a%3E%20is%20the%20place%20to%20talk%20about%20things%20like%20what%20questions%20are%20appropriate,%20what%20tags%20we%20should%20use,%20etc.';%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20$('#system-message-temp').html(curSystemMessage).attr('id', 'system-message');        </script>        </div>        <div id="content">            <div class="subheader">    <h1>Log In</h1></div><div id="mainbar">        <div class="page-description">                                <div class="form-error">                    </div>                       <p>                <span class="revision-comment">Warning: this site is currently in <b>private beta</b> for at least 2 more days</span>.            </p>            <p>                To log in, you must have commited to the <a href="http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/lookup/politics.stackexchange.com">Area 51 site proposal</a>                and received the invitation email. Click the invitation link in the email to log in!              </p>    </div>        </div> <div id="sidebar">        <div class="module newuser">            <h4>Why OpenID?</h4>            <p>It&rsquo;s a single username and password that allows you to log in to any OpenID-enabled site.</p>            <p>It works on thousands of websites.</p>            <p>It&rsquo;s an open standard.</p>            <p class="ar">            <a href="http://openid.net/what/">learn more &raquo;</a><br>            </p>        </div></div><br class="cbt">        </div>    </div>    <div id="footer">        <div class="footerwrap">            <div id="footer-menu">                <a href="/about">about</a> |                <a href="/faq">faq</a> |                <a href="http://blog.stackexchange.com?blb=1">blog</a> |                    <a href="http://chat.stackexchange.com">chat</a> |                <a href="http://data.stackexchange.com">data</a> |                <a href="http://stackexchange.com/legal">legal</a> |                <a href="http://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy">privacy policy</a> |                <a href="http://stackexchange.com/about/hiring">jobs</a> |                <a href="http://stackexchange.com/about/contact">advertising info</a> |                <a onclick="StackExchange.switchMobile('on', '/users/login?returnurl=%2fmobile%2fon')">mobile</a> |                <b><a href="/help">contact us</a></b>                  | <b><a href="http://meta.politics.stackexchange.com">feedback</a></b>                <div id="footer-sites">                    <span style="color:#46937D;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://area51.stackexchange.com">area 51</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;                <span style="color:#FE7A15;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://stackapps.com">api/apps</a>                </div>            </div>            <div id="footer-flair">                <a class="peer1" href="http://www.peer1.com/stackoverflow"></a>              <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/" class="cc-wiki-link"></a>                <div id="svnrev">rev 2012.12.8.548</div>                        </div>            <div id="copyright">                site design / logo &copy; 2012 stack exchange inc;                 user contributions licensed under <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/" rel="license">cc-wiki</a> with <a href="http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/" rel="license">attribution required</a>            </div>                    </div>    </div>        <noscript>        <div id="noscript-warning">Politics - Stack Exchange works best with JavaScript enabled<img src="http://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel/p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc.gif" alt="" class="dno"></div>    </noscript>    <script type="text/javascript">var _gaq=_gaq||[];_gaq.push(['_setAccount','UA-5620270-24']);        _gaq.push(['_setDomainName','.stackexchange.com']);_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);    var _qevents = _qevents || [];    (function(){        var s=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];        var ga=document.createElement('script');        ga.type='text/javascript';        ga.async=true;        ga.src='http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js';        s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga,s);        var sc=document.createElement('script');        sc.type='text/javascript';        sc.async=true;        sc.src='http://edge.quantserve.com/quant.js';         s.parentNode.insertBefore(sc,s);    })();    </script>    <script type="text/javascript">        _qevents.push({ qacct: "p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc" });    </script>        </body></html>`
   ```

Comment: Simply going to http://politics.stackexchange.com and clicking the mobile link does the same thing (at least for me - not a beta member). That's one hell of a URL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Haha, this one cracked me up.  It'll be fixed in the next build.

Explanation: the route this thing posts to in order to set your mobile cookie was not in the "don't have to be logged in" exception list and itself redirected to the login page.  It's now on that magical list, with the other unicorns.

Comment: I don't know what you just said, but it contained the words magical and unicorn. +1

Comment: Is this a covert promotion for North Korea?